# setContentOffset not scrolling my UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to scroll my UITableViewCell up one UITableViewCell position when the selected cell reaches the last position in the UITableView

I have the logic correct for identifying the last visible UItableViewCell of the UITableView. However the code to make the UITableView scroll up one position is not working. This is the code I have written.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cellSelectedBool = YES;

    cell = (CustomFinishingCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; // error
    [cell.widthTexField becomeFirstResponder];


    // Gets an array of current visible cells in UITableView
    NSArray *visibleCells = [tableView visibleCells];
    NSLog(@"%@", visibleCells);
    // get indexpath of last cell
    UITableViewCell *lastCell = [visibleCells lastObject];
    NSIndexPath *lastCellIndex = [finishingTableView indexPathForCell:lastCell];
    // perform scroll when last visible cell is selected
    if (indexPath.row == lastCellIndex.row) {
        NSLog(@"BIGGER");
        int cellHeight = 44;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:.25 animations:^{
            [finishingTableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(finishingTableView.contentOffset.x,finishingTableView.contentOffset.y + cellHeight) animated:YES];
        }];
    }
```

Comment: I think you are trying to scroll it down (and it can't go any further...). Try `finishingTableView.contentOffset.y - cellHeight`

Answer (score 2):

you should use:

```
NSIndexPath *rowToSelect;  // assume this exists and is set properly
UITableView *myTableView;  // assume this exists

[myTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:rowToSelect animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
[myTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:rowToSelect atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:YES];
```

Comment: okay this works.... however didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not being called if the user hits enter on the UIKeyBoard and is currently on the last row.. however if I select the last row with my finger it will call didSelectRowAtIndexPath then work.....

Answer (score 0):

```
if (indexPath.row == lastCellIndex.row) {
    [finishingTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPathatScrollPosition:
        UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:YES];
}
```